# How to retrieve the last record in each group with DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

As for MySQL, I know how to retrive the last record in each group, such as:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM devops.clearquest_clearquest 
  ORDER BY 'created_at' DESC
) AS A 
GROUP BY A.submitter;
```

But DB2 is a little bit different, you can only select column which is used after **GROUP BY**, like this:

```
SELECT A.submitter 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM devops.clearquest_clearquest 
  ORDER BY 'created_at' DESC
) AS A 
GROUP BY A.submitter;
```

So, if I want to fetch two columns, I need to GROUP BY them like this:

```
SELECT A.column01, A.column02 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM devops.clearquest_clearquest 
  ORDER BY 'created_at' DESC
) AS A 
GROUP BY A.column01, A.column02;
```

here comes the problem, I can't retrieve the last record in each group if I GROUP BY two columns. I'm new to DB2, please help.

Comment: The fact that your MySQL query "works" is pure coincidence - it is invalid SQL and instead of rejecting it, MySQL simply  returns a random result.

Comment: Why are you sorting by a constant string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not proper SQL:

```
SELECT cc.* 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM devops.clearquest_clearquest 
      ORDER BY created_at DESC
     ) cc
GROUP BY cc.submitter;
```

Note:  *No* quotes around `created_at`.

Because you have columns in the `SELECT` that are not `GROUP BY` keys and not the arguments to aggregation functions.  This will return a syntax error in almost all databases.  Happily, it will also break in the more recent versions of MySQL (with the default options).

Often the most efficient equivalent is:

```
select cc.*
from devops.clearquest_clearquest cc
where cc.created_at = (select max(cc2.created_at)
                       from devops.clearquest_clearquest cc2
                       where cc2.submitter = cc.submitter
                      );
```

With an index on `devops.clearquest_clearquest(submitter, created_at)`, this is often the fastest approach in any database.

Other answers have provided the answer using `row_number()`.  That is also a very good solution, but often a wee bit slower, because the row number is assigned to *all* rows before most are filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

It is a classical greatest per group task and I would use some standard solution such as

```
SELECT cc.*
FROM devops.clearquest_clearquest cc 
JOIN (
    SELECT A.submitter, max('created_at') max_created_at
    FROM devops.clearquest_clearquest A
    GROUP BY A.submitter
) t ON cc.submitter = t.submitter 
   and cc.'created_at' = t.max_created_at
```

or window functions

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      row_number() over (partition by submitter order by 'created_at' desc) rn
    FROM devops.clearquest_clearquest 
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Please note that the behaviour of MySQL is not 'standard'. Most of the database systems do not allow to include columns behind `SELECT` if they are not part of the `GROUP BY` or aggregate function. If you set `sql_mode` of MySQL to [ANSI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/compatibility.html) then your query will not pass.

Comment: Isn't the `INNER JOIN` clause missing from your first query? Also, the `A` alias isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

In Db2 you can do this to get the row with the highest `created_at` date within each group `column01, column02`.

Wwell, strictly speaking it would be *one of the rows* that has the highest `created_at` in each group. `ROW_NUMBER()` is non-deterministic if `created_at, column01, column02` is not unique

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    ,    row_number() over (
                  partition by A.column01, A.column02
                  order by "created_at" desc) rn
    FROM devops.clearquest_clearquest A
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Note that column names need to be surrounded by double quotes (and not single quotes) if they are not upper-case in the table defintion

Answer (score 1):

You can query the table and join it to itself to get the max date (or whatever you want to group by/find

For example,

```
select t1.submitter, XXGroup2, t2.maxdate from
    (select * FROM devops.clearquest_clearquest) t1
        inner join
    (SELECT submitter, XXGroup2, max(created_at) as maxdate 
     FROM devops.clearquest_clearquest 
     GROUP BY XXGroup1, XXGroup2) t2                                                    
        on t1.submitter = t2.submitter AND t1.XXGROUP2 = t2.XXGROUP2
)                                                                       
order by t1.submitter, t1.XXGROUP2
```